# In Boruto, are there other people with Karmas?

Tags: boruto

I've been watching *Boruto* and the way people get Karmas. There are other strong villages: have they not been attacked? And, if they have defeated them, are there any other Karmas besides Boruto's and Kawaki's?

Answer (score 3):

There are only 4 people with the Karma

(Kāma) seal that we know as of yet :-

- [Kawaki](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Kawaki)
- [Boruto](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Boruto_Uzumaki)
- [Jigen](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Jigen)
- [Code](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Code)

You can find the wiki source for the above claims [here](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/K%C4%81ma)

It is currently unknown if any other person has this seal.

Out of the above 4 people the only Code has a White Karma(Kāma) seal on him. Rest all have Black Karma(Kāma) seal on them. While Jigen having passed away, we can assume that only 3 people currently have Karma.

> Due to Isshiki leaving his body, and having little to no chakra at
> all, he passed away.

Kawaki had also lost his Karma(Kāma) but regained it later. Below is a reference from the wiki :-

> By the improper resurrection of Isshiki, Kawaki's being has mostly
> been written into Isshiki's likeness. This forced resurrection of
> Isshiki also resulted Kawaki's Kāma being erased. Later however, he
> was branded with another Kāma.

Also there is no known instance of people with Karma(Kāma) seal attacking the other villages. The leaf was attacked only because they have 2 people with Karma(Kāma) in their village - Kawaki and Boruto respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are other people with Karma.

All four introductions to the Karma have included the following characters:

- *[Jigen](https://boruto.fandom.com/wiki/Jigen)* / *[Isshiki Otsutsuki](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Isshiki_%C5%8Ctsutsuki)*
- [*Kawaki*](https://boruto.fandom.com/wiki/Kawaki)
- [*Boruto Uzumaki*](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Boruto_Uzumaki)
- ... and *[Code](https://boruto.fandom.com/wiki/Code)*.

Some of them had different ways of getting the Karma, for example, Boruto got his after defeating Momoshiki Otsutsuki with his father-son Giant Rasengan. Kawaki, on the other hand, got his through scientific experiments (through Amado) / Jigen's chakra. Code got his the same way as Kawaki, though his was a white Karma and was a non-vessel weapon.

There are no other known characters to possess a Karma other than the four mentioned, but some have lost theirs:

- Jigen lost his after being killed by Koji Kashin.
- ... and Kawaki had lost his by a Karma safety feature after Isshiki was forced to resurrect through Jigen's body, which, of course, limited his lifespan to about two days. (Until shortened by Naruto's Baryon Mode.)

Which leaves only Code (White, non-vessel Karma) and Boruto to *currently* be the only characters shown to possess any form of the Karma. Villages were not really *intended* to be attacked by Otsutsuki, but to just fulfill their goal of planting the Divine Tree, which would require a living Otsutsuki, which the Leaf Village sort of possesses, because of Boruto's Karma.